# NSURLConnection response not complete

Tags: xcode, nsurlconnection, nsjsonserialization

I am making call to a server requesting JSON data using NSURLConnection.

For some reason I get part of the response. If I hit the url through the browser the response its correct. The weird thing is that it happens only sometime. So I'm having a hard time debugging the issue.

Then when because the response is not complete I get the following error:
*Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0xa4634a0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} {
    NSDebugDescription = "Invalid value around character 0.";
}*

I guess it could also be an issue with the server it self. Here's my code:

```
-(void) getShareHistory:(NSString *)range paging:(NSInteger *)page{
     NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"range=%@&paging=%@",
                      range,
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)page]];
     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www/domai.com/handle_share_links.php?action=history"];
     NSData *post_data = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
     NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [post_data length]];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
     [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
     [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     [request setHTTPBody:post_data];

     self.shareHistoryConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)response{
     NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"response %@",strData);
     NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
     if(connection == self.shareHistoryConn)
     {
        NSArray *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
    if(!jsonParsingError)
    {
        [[self delegate] onGetShareHistorySuccess:data];
    }else{
        [[self delegate] onGetShareHistoryFailed:jsonParsingError];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal behavior. `didReceiveData` can be called any number of times. It is up to you to keep accumulating the data until you get `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

The standard delegate structure is like this:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // connection is starting, clear buffer
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // data is arriving, add it to the buffer
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection
        didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // something went wrong, clean up interface as needed
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // all done, we are ready to rock and roll
    // do something with self.receivedData
}
```

Always implement all four delegate methods.

Comment: And for more info, see the relevant section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests

Comment: That was exactly the issue. thanks again. 

I would add the initialization of the object to your answer in the didReceiveResponse self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0] instead.

Comment: Not a bad idea, thanks. If you're going to do that, by the way, you may as well just say `[NSMutableData new]`.

Comment: I've been debugging the same for a while, and was about to implement a complex hack to try to get this to work. I wish this was documented slightly better. But thank you very much matt! This was exactly my problem.